# What is the best way to compare two objects having multiple list attributes

Tags: java, list, comparator, comparable

I have a POJO/DTO class with multiple list attribute like

```java
class Boo {    
    private List<Foo> foos;
    private List<Integer> pointers;
}
```

I want to compare if both lists contain the same values ignoring the order of the lists. Is it possible to achieve this without opening the object and ordering the lists?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can they contain the same values?  Does `Foo` have an `Integer`?

Comment: What do you mean by `opening` the objets ? Also why would you order your list if it doesn't matter ?

Comment: I think OP wants to compare two `List<Boo>`, which would include comparing their class attributes, too. Or maybe just compare two instances of `Boo`.

Comment: You could use sets. Compare the size and if `a.containsAll(b)`, then both sets are equal.

Comment: well, at any case the comparison comes down to the `equals` implementation. it's really wide problem and the question must be much more uncovered to identify the way of resolving

Comment: Nexevis Does it matter? Say I am getting this values from some external endpoints. they are not guarantee of order but equal values are expected. I need to compare latest one with previous one. Hope This will help you

Comment: Thanks Guys for the your Input, I know the long way of fixing this issue just looking for a smart way.

Comment: @deepesh kumar Yes it matters?  A `Foo` is never equal to an `Integer`.  Are you attempting to check a `Boo` to a `Boo`? Because thats not what you wrote.  If you meant `Foo` to `Integer` then `Foo` must have an `Integer` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I want to compare if both contains same values instead of the order of list."*

There is not a universal equality operator. Sometimes you want compare objects by certain properties. Probably the canonical example could be comparing strings, sometimes "computer" is equal or not than "Computer" or "Vesterålen" is equal or not than "Vesteralen".

In *Java*, you can **redefine** the **default** equivalence relation between objects (modifying the default behavior!).

The object `List` use as default equivalence relation the default equivalence relation of the contained objects and checking that equality in order.

The following example ignore the elements order only in one property:

```
class My {
    private final List<String> xs;
    private final List<Integer> ys;

    My(List<String> xs, List<Integer> ys) {
        this.xs = xs;
        this.ys = ys;
    }

    public List<Integer> getYs() {
        return ys;
    }

    public List<String> getXs() {
        return xs;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return xs.hashCode() + 7 * ys.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof My))
            return false;
        My o = (My) obj;
        return
                // ignoring order
                getXs().stream().sorted().collect(toList()).equals(o.getXs().stream().sorted().collect(toList()))
                // checking order
                && getYs().equals(o.getYs());
    }
}

public class Callme {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        My m1 = new My(asList("a", "b"), asList(1, 2));
        My m2 = new My(asList("b", "a"), asList(1, 2));
        My m3 = new My(asList("a", "b"), asList(2, 1));
        System.out.println(m1.equals(m2));
        System.out.println(m1.equals(m3));
    }
}
```

with output

```
true
false
```

But **I can't define YOUR required equivalence relation**, for example I do not ignore if one list contains more elements than the other but maybe you wish (eg. to you is equal `{a, b, a}` than `{b, a}`).

So, define you equivalence relation for your object and override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: This can be done, Cant change collection but off course can implement equals

Comment: @deepeshkumar I don't get you. Yes, you must to define what equivalence relation do you want and then, override `hashCode` and `equals` (my code is an example).

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to comparing the lists. If the order of the items is irrelevant anyways you might fare better using `Set` instead of `List`.

Your equals then would look like

```java
public boolean equals(object other) {
    //here be class and null checks
    return foos.equals(other.foos) && pointers.equals(other.pointers);
}
```

If you cannot use Set - either because you can have the same item multiple times or because order matters - you have can do the same as above with a reciprocal `containsAll()` call. This still would not take duplicate entries into consideration but will work quite fine otherwise.

You state that you cannot edit the class `Boo`. One solution would be to have a service class which does this for you a bit similar to `Objects.equals()`.

```java
class BooComparer {

    public static bool equals(Boo a, Boo b) {
        //again do some null checks here
        return a.foos.containsAll(b.foos) 
          && b.foos.containsAll(a.foos)
          && a.pointers.containsAll(b.pointers)
          && b.pointers.containsAll(a.pointers)
    }
}
```

If this works for you - fine. Maybe you have to compare other members, too. And again: this will ignore if one of the lists has an entry twice.

Comment: Correct I agree with you. I have my hands tied. Can't change the class. It is as per api specification.

Comment: @deepesh can't change which class?

Comment: If you cannot implement the equals of the class you have to implement an external comparison like ```Objects.equals()```. I will update my answer accordingly.